# How to use ndk-stack in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to debug my android app which uses androidNDK.
I am not using default androidNDK of android studio.I have downloaded androidNDK separately.Using this androidNDK I built the SO file.
Now to debug the crash from stack,
I followed this link 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html

To do stack trace they mentioned command

```
$NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi -dump foo.txt
```

I replaced $NDK with the path of my downloaded androidNDK.
-sym file gives me confusion 
What is symbol file??
Which filepath  should I include?
Either the c project filepath or my android studio file path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.
-sym projectpathtomysofile
-sym file path  is the file path of my **so file** in my android studio project.

```
$NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi -dump foo.txt
```

**$NDK**--- Need to mention the path of androidNDK in my system.
**ndk-stack** --- is the executable program.
**-sym** --- argument mentioning the path of the symbol file which is my so file path in my android studio.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old question, but maybe you remember, how can I get this .so file and could you give me an example of full working command?  I'm facing the same issue. I'd be realy grateful, thanks.

Comment: @JanRozenbajgier https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack follow this hopefully it can explain u

Comment: i used to builds so file separately by building c and c ++ projects and then put them in android project